# Параметры в строке запроса

Tags: php

Друзья у меня есть строка типа

```
http://proffupack.ru/catalog/?grp=7260
```

Я хочу ввести новый параметр: typeview с 2мя значениями: list и gallery

Так вот как сделать что бы к изначальной строке дописывался этот параметр ? Я сделал вот так но у меня не прокатило:

```
<a href="&typeview=list">Список</a> | <a href="&typeview=gallery">Галерея</a>
```

Comment: На данный момент если я нажимаю кнопку то ?grp=7260 пропадает, а нехотелось бы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://proffupack.ru/catalog/?grp=7260&typeview=list">Список</a>
<a href="http://proffupack.ru/catalog/?grp=7260&typeview=gallery">Галерея</a>
```

Ну URI, понятно, сделать динамическим.

Answer (score 1):

Надо получить адрес текущей страницы, и дописывать к нему оба варианта параметра:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
printf(
    '<a href="%1$s&typeview=list">Список</a> | <a href="%1$s&typeview=gallery">Галерея</a>', 
    $url
);
```